# Angular 2 unable to import Service from different directory

Tags: angular

```
app
|-ComponentA
|-ComponentB
|-Service
```

I have made directories for each Component and separate directory for all the services...

when i tried to import service into component A as well as for B

```
import {ClickedRowItemService} from 'app/Service/customerrowclick.service';
```

the compiler was unable to detect module and after searching on SO I found this answer:
Add this in tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "app/*",
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and then changing import statement as below solved the compiler error and compiler was able to detect module:

```
import {ClickedRowItemService} from 'Service/customerrowclick.service';
```

but when running on browser console-inspect Im getting the error again as:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/Service/customerrowclick.service 404 (Not Found)
```

trying to fix the same from yesterday... Pls help!!!

Comment: Try related path `import {ClickedRowItemService} from '../Service/customerrowclick.service';`  and see if it's work.

Comment: @AvneshShakya man i dono hw to thank u.. that worked :-D

Comment: I am glad, worked for you.

Comment: if you can post an answer i ll be accepting it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **relative path** from your `component.ts` like this:

```
import {ClickedRowItemService} from '../Service/customerrowclick.service';
```

and see if it works.